# move actor to position where user clicks in gamesalad

Tags: gamesalad

I am new to gamesalad.

I want to move my actor where person clicks.

I can't find the way how to do it.

I am able to move it to specific position (coordinates) but cannot move it to clicked coordinates.

can anyone please help ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already know how 'actor' can be moved to specific position, so that it is simple.
Just, change the position to 'game.Touches.Touch 1.X' in 'Move To' behavior.

[image: Move To Behaviour]

'Position' value is below.

Position X : game.Touches.Touch 1.X

Position Y : game.Touches.Touch 1.Y

Comment: can you please also tell me how to move that actor back to same position after collision to other actor ???

Comment: Hi, there. Unfortunately, I'm going to travelling recently, so I can't explain to your question in detail. I think there are various methods for doing this behaviour. You can record actor's position by using 'attribute' or just change scene to 'Game Start' screen if actor's position before collision is the same in 'Game Start'. I'd recommend to watch very simple and essencial tutorial. [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WkAgEfNVoDY)